# Python None check not working

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm using the following Python code

```
    q = myMember.query(myMember.user==user)
    u = q.get()
    if u is None:
        self.redirect('/AddMember')
    elif u.team is None:
        self.redirect('/AddMember')
    elif u.team == "None":
        self.redirect('/AddMember')

    values = set_values()
    values['team'] = u.team
```

When I run I get this error:

```
     values['team'] = u.team
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'team'
```

Why isn't the NoneType getting caught in the if clauses?

Comment: `if` doesn't "catch" stuff, it just... um...  *does* stuff.

Comment: I took the redirect to mean it would break from the function  - way to encourage questions

Comment: It is not possible to write such a function in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if u is None:
    self.redirect('/AddMember')
```

This code piece should have a *return* statement. It keeps on running, hence the exception.

Answer (score 1):

The `if` block does execute, but the function keeps executing, so the later lines still happen.  If you want to stop the function you need to return or raise an exception.  Or you could put the last lines into an `else` so they only happen if none of the if/elif conditions are met.